# Override plugin function to show invoices even if not logged in

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, nonce, plugin-json-api

I am using [WooCommerce Print Invoice](https://woocommerce.com/products/print-invoices-packing-lists/) plugin to print invoices.
Now I am working on a Cordova app for my website and I need to be able to see invoices from wordpress.

Plugin has a function to hide or redirect page if you are not logged in.

```
public function print_document_action() {

        // listen for 'print' action query string
        if (isset($_GET['wc_pip_document'], $_GET['wc_pip_action']) && 'print' === $_GET['wc_pip_action']) {

            // sanity check, if user is not logged in, prompt to log in
            if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
                wp_redirect(wc_get_page_permalink('myaccount'));
                exit;
            }

            $nonce = isset($_REQUEST['_wpnonce']) ? $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] : '';

            // security admin/frontend checks
            if (!$nonce || !wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'wc_pip_document')) {
                die(__('You are not allowed to view this page.', 'woocommerce-pip'));
            }
```

Can this be overwritten from functions.php?

Tried to use entire function again, without those lines like this:

```
add_filter('print_document_action', 'showInvoices', $priority = 9999, $args = 1);
function showInvoices() {
    // same function without sanity check and security admin/frontend checks
}
```

Tried also to generate nounce with JSON API plugin and run page like this:

```
site.com/orders/?wc_pip_action=print&wc_pip_document=invoice&order_id='+id+'&_wpnonce='+nonce;
```

This also is not working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the plugin function from the filter.

Are you sure the plugin function and the filter have the same name!

*You will need to know the priority that the plugin function is using to use it in remove_filter, I will assume It's the default (10).

```
remove_filter( 'print_document_action', 'print_document_action', 10 );
```

Then add your function to the filter.

```
add_filter('print_document_action', 'showInvoices', $priority = 9999, $args = 1);
```

Comment: it's not working, tried with different priority values too

Comment: You must use the same priority value that plugin function is using.

Comment: yes, but I don't know what is it. How can I find it?